# Basic Webpack ExtractTextWebpackPlugin configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a problem configuring ExtractTextWebpackPlugin for simpy including separate CSS files in my HTML head tag (using link tag), which is its main purpose i believe.

My current configuration in *webpack.config.js*:

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: "app.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('general.css')
  ]
};
```

In my main *index.js* file i have `require("../style.css");`

*style.css* is placed in project root folder.

In my *index.html* i have `<script src="dist/app.js"></script>`

As i understand this should inlclude *general.css* in my *head* tag at runtime but it is not there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell what error you are getting?
Like any sort of error in page or console

Comment: there are different version of extractTextPlugin for webpack 2 & webpack, make sure to install proper one.

Comment: @Niraj i am not getting any errors, everything builds and runs fine with no errors but i don't get ther results. Version of extractTextPlugin i use is *2.1.0* and webpack *2.3.3*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExtractTextPlugin` only removes the CSS from your bundle to decouple it from the JavaScript and you need to include it in your HTML, as well as the bundle.

You can automate this by letting webpack generate an HTML file for you. That is especially useful when you use hashes in your file names. You'll need to use the [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) which will automatically include the bundled JavaScript as well as the CSS extracted by the `ExtractTextPlugin`.

Additionally, you should understand that your idea of including the CSS at runtime would negatively affect the load time of your page, because you would first need to download the JavaScript bundle (1st network request) then you would need to execute the JS, which takes some time to be parsed, and after that you'll have to download your CSS file  (2nd network request). Since you depend on the bundle to be executed first, you will display your page without CSS for a brief moment, or a substantial amount of time on a low end mobile device with a bad network connection.

This is basically what happens if you don't use the `ExtractTextPlugin` and instead use the `style-loader`. The `style-loader` simply injects your CSS into a `<style>` tag, which is done from your JavaScript bundle, so it still depends on the bundle being executed but at least it doesn't need an extra network request for the CSS. That is even better than what you expected `ExtractTextPlugin` to do, which would effectively make the plugin useless.

Comment: I actually meant to write buildtime not runtime. Made an error there :) But still you made a valid point about runtime execution. Using *html-webpack-plugin* is the way to go, so i am marking this as the correct answer. Thanks Michael.